# CSS Center link and fill bar to end of page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to **vertically align the text inside my nav bar**.

Ive tried using vertical-align. But its not working.

Ive also made sure its got height to actually align inside.

Also, is there a way to **fill the nav bar to the end of the page**, a parallogram/rectangle. So that there is no white space on right of the links. So it is effectively one long bar, split by parallograms.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4kUm/

```
 <ul id="navlist">
                        <li><a><span>Link</span></a></li>
                        <li><a><span>Link</span></a></li>
                        <li><a><span>Link</span></a></li>
                         <li><a><span>Link</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

My css:

```
ul#navlist {
    padding:10px;
    font: bold 12px Arial, sans-serif;
   display: inline;
}

ul#navlist li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    position:relative;
    width:125px;
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    color:#757575;
}

ul#navlist li a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 10px;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
     width:115px;
     height: 40px;

}

ul#navlist li a span 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: skewX(20deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
}

ul#navlist li a {
    background:#AAA;
}
```

Comment: "display: table-cell" may help but it doesn't work on IE7 or below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `line-height` property on the spans to match their height.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z4kUm/1/)**

```
ul#navlist li a span 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 
    line-height:40px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: skewX(20deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! Do you know how to extend the bar to the end of page (not as a link)

Comment: I'd imagine you'd need to change the width of the list items, depending oh how exactly you want it to look.